# Mapping Unsaved value DateTime with fluent nhibernate

Tags: oracle, datetime, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am mapping a table with a composite key with Fluent NHibernate. I want to ask if anyone knows what the value of unsaved DateTime should be.
I have written "XXXXXXXX" in the code sample where the default value should be inserted.

I can now see that you can only set unsaved value once. If you set it for each key you will get an error when Fluent creates the hbm.xml file.
So somehow we need to specify both key values in one string.

The backend is Oracle and I am mapping to Date.

```
internal class BondRawAccruedDataMap : ClassMap<BondRawAccruedData>
{
    public BondRawAccruedDataMap()
    {
        Schema("fpd");
        Table("bond_accrued_raw_data");

        CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.Instrument, "instrument").UnsavedValue("0")
                     .KeyProperty(x => x.RunDate, "run_date").UnsavedValue(DateTime.MinValue.ToString(XXXXXXXXXXXX));
        Map(x => x.SettleDate, "settle_date");
        Map(x => x.AccruedInterest, "accrued_interest");
        Map(x => x.AccruedFactor, "accrued_factor");
        Map(x => x.PrincipalFactor, "principal_factor"); 
        Map(x => x.InterestDaysSinceCoupon, "days_acc");
    }
}
```

Updated mapping

```
internal class BondRawAccruedDataMap : ClassMap<BondRawAccruedData>
{
    public BondRawAccruedDataMap()
    {
        Schema("fpd");
        Table("bond_accrued_raw_data");

        CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.Instrument, "instrument")
                     .KeyProperty(x => x.RunDate, "run_date").UnsavedValue("Unsaved value for instrument and rundate");
        Map(x => x.SettleDate, "settle_date");
        Map(x => x.AccruedInterest, "accrued_interest");
        Map(x => x.AccruedFactor, "accrued_factor");
        Map(x => x.PrincipalFactor, "principal_factor"); 
        Map(x => x.InterestDaysSinceCoupon, "days_acc");
    }
}
```